# cant read custom section from web config

Tags: c#, web-config, custom-sections

Why can't I read this from my web config? When I used App.config it worked fine..

> FundGroups = null

```
private static readonly NameValueCollection FundGroups =
        (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("FundGroups");
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<configSections>
    <section name="FundGroups" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
</configSections>

<FundGroups>
<add key="Group1" value="Value1" />
<add key="Group2" value="Value2" />
<add key="Group3" value="Value3" />
<add key="Group4" value="Value4" />
<add key="Group5" value="Value5" />
<add key="Group6" value="Value6" />
<add key="Group7" value="Value7" />
</FundGroups>


</configuration>
```

I found a possible duplication [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461418/how-to-get-the-values-of-a-configurationsection-of-type-namevaluesectionhandler). But the ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig seems to be obsolete and doesnt work for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the values of a ConfigurationSection of type NameValueSectionHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461418/how-to-get-the-values-of-a-configurationsection-of-type-namevaluesectionhandler)

Comment: The answer there, by using ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig is obsolete...