# Custom config section is causing Configuration to fail to load

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have [added a link to my app.config file to my unit test project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528427/197229) and it works, I can see the config values listed. However when I add a custom section as discussed here ([How to get the values of a ConfigurationSection of type NameValueSectionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461418/how-to-get-the-values-of-a-configurationsection-of-type-namevaluesectionhandler)) to my XML, ConfigurationManager shows as being in an invalid state in the debugger.

My app.config ends like this:
[image]

MSDN says we're not supposed to use the older pre .NET 2 config classes as they are deprecated. So I'm not sure what can be wrong here?

Comment: In the section, try to use `<section name="MyTest" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration" />`. Also don't use pictures.

Comment: What does the 2nd element control - have you got a link?

Comment: It's a reference to its assembly. I've got it in my project.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Then show us please, how you call the `ConfigurationManager`. And how you read the custom section value.

Answer (score 0):

Aha... I had thought no errors were being logged but found this was being reported which clears it up:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration
>   system failed to initialize --->
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Only one
>    element allowed per config file and if present must
>   be the first child of the root  element.

Comment: I think you might want `type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"` not `AppSettingsSection` ?

Comment: According to MSDN this is deprecated, though it's confusing because lots of examples use it.