# How to read custom section from app config or web config in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, web-config

I want to read custom section from app config and web config in C#. Section contain nested nodes(not key value pair). I have already read it using StreamReader class but the problem is that when I create SQL connection then it give exception like "Bad configuration in config file". So, is there any other way to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461418/how-to-get-the-values-of-a-configurationsection-of-type-namevaluesectionhandler

Comment: What have you done so far? can you include it?

Comment: 1. I have read my custom section using StreamReader class but when I try to SqlConnection then it gives "Bad configuration".                                                2. I have tried to register my section using configSection but not working because I don't have key value pair in my custom section.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i knew:

`Web.config` or `app.config` file depend on System.Configuration dll

if you have wrote any none of that Configuration dll it will return you to an exception error message:

unless you have to create your own [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c) file and read its content.