# Get the configsection data from app.config

Tags: c#-4.0

Trying to loop through app.config file, searched the posts but haven't had luck

```
app.config

 <configSections>
    <section name="US" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    <section name="UK" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
 </configSections>

  <US>
    <add key="UserName" value="test" />
    <add key="Password" value="test" />
    <add key="baseURI" value="http://test.com />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </US>

  <UK>
   <add key="UserName" value="test1 />
    <add key="Password" value="test1 />
    <add key="baseURI" value="http://test1.com />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </UK>
```

I need to loop through app.config file and get the key value data like the below for US and UK sections.

```
*Result:*

Section : US

Username: test
Password: test
baseURI: http://test.com

Section : UK

Username: test1
Password: test1
baseURI: http://test1.com
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the values of a ConfigurationSection of type NameValueSectionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461418/how-to-get-the-values-of-a-configurationsection-of-type-namevaluesectionhandler)

Comment: Try using an AppSettingsSection instead of a NameValueCollection. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14384706/336511

Comment: I tried the way in the samples, but I get the error ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled (An unhandled exception of type "System.Configurartion.ConfigurationErrorsException" occurred in System.Configuration.dll
C#
   var section = (AppSettingsSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("USMailSettings");  --  error configuration error exception
                string results = section.Settings["UserName"].Value;

Comment: there's no USMailSettings config in ys sample! use `(AppSettingsSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("US");`

Comment: I tried it but get the same ConfigurationErrorsException

Comment: did u try my answer? @josh

Answer (score 0):

There are some problem with yr config file, you are missing some quotes("), plz correct it first.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <!--This MUST be the first node-->
  <configSections>
    <section name="US" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection"/>
    <section name="UK" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection"/>
  </configSections>

  <US>
    <add key="UserName" value="test" />
    <add key="Password" value="test" />
    <add key="baseURI" value="http://test.com" /> <!--misssing a " here!! -->
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </US>

  <UK>
    <add key="UserName" value="test1" /><!--misssing a " here!! -->
    <add key="Password" value="test1" /><!--misssing a " here!! -->
    <add key="baseURI" value="http://test1.com" /><!--misssing a " here!! -->
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </UK>        

</configuration>
```

and then in yr code just use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` to get the configuration object:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var section = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("UK");

var results = section.Settings["UserName"].Value;

Console.WriteLine(results);
```

Comment: Fixed my config file and tried but I get appSettingSection does not contain the definition for Setting and no extension method for Setting.

var results = section.Settings["UserName"].Value; - ERROR

Comment: can u put yr whole app.config here?

Comment: <configSections>
    <section name="US" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection"/>
    <section name="UK" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection"/>
 </configSections>
  <US>
    <add key="UserName" value="test1" />
    <add key="Password" value="test1" />
    <add key="baseURI" value="http://test1.com" />
     </US>

 <UK>
  <add key="UserName" value="test2" />
  <add key="Password" value="test2" />
  <add key="baseURI" value="http://test2.com" />
 </UK>

Comment: there are two ; in yr config. remove them!

Comment: I do not have ; in my code...when I copied somehow it got there.

Comment: that's impossible